# How do I make schema dependencies in react json form to show in one row

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-4, react-forms, react-jsonschema-forms

I'm using react json schema form (https://react-jsonschema-form.readthedocs.io/) to create a form rendered via a schema. I'm trying to generate a schema dependency where based on the selection of a drop down different types of form fields are generated.

I created the json schema in this form:

```
{
            "title": "Query Builder",
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
                "SelectCriteria": {
                    "title": "",
                    "type": "array",
                    "items": {
                        "$ref": "#/definitions/criteria"
                    }
                }
            },
            "definitions": {
                "nestedGroup": {
                    "title": "Nested Group",
                    "type": "object",
                    "properties": {
                        "SelectCriteria": {
                            "title": "",
                            "type": "array",
                            "items": {
                                "$ref": "#/definitions/criteria"
                            },
                            "maxItems": 1
                        }
                    }
                },
                "stringList": {
                    "title": "",
                    "type": "object",
                    "properties": {
                        "Select Operator": {
                            "type": "string",
                            "enum": ["Equals", "Contains"]
                        },
                        "value": {
                            "type": "string"
                        }
                    },
                    "required": ["Select Operator", "value"]
                },
                "range": {
                    "title": "",
                    "type": "object",
                    "properties": {
                        "Select Operator": {
                            "type": "string",
                            "enum": ["Equals", "Contains"]
                        },
                        "from": {
                            "type": "number"
                        },
                        "to": {
                            "type": "number"
                        }
                    },
                    "required": ["Select Operator"]
                },
                "criteria": {
                    "title": "",
                    "type": "object",
                    "properties": {
                        "Select Criteria": {
                            "type": "string",
                            "enum": ["Customer reviews", "Popularity Score", "nestedGroup"]
                        },
                        "isNot": {
                            "type": "boolean"
                        }
                    },
                    "required": ["Select Criteria"],
                    "dependencies": {
                        "Select Criteria": {
                            "oneOf": [
                                {
                                    "properties": {
                                        "Select Criteria": {
                                            "enum": ["nestedGroup"]
                                        },
                                        "items": {
                                            "$ref": "#/definitions/nestedGroup"
                                        }
                                    }
                                },
                                {
                                    "properties": {
                                        "Select Criteria": {
                                            "enum": ["Customer reviews"]
                                        },
                                        "items": {
                                            "$ref": "#/definitions/stringList"
                                        }
                                    }
                                },
                                {
                                    "properties": {
                                        "Select Criteria": {
                                            "enum": ["Popularity Score"]
                                        },
                                        "items": {
                                            "$ref": "#/definitions/range"
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

However as can be seen by testing this in json schema playground (https://rjsf-team.github.io/react-jsonschema-form/) it generates the Select operator and the corresponding value box below each other. Is there a way to make everything in a single row?

I looked into using this https://github.com/audibene-labs/react-jsonschema-form-layout to layout the different form elements, but I wasn't able to figure out what the uiSchema should look like. Any suggestions? I'm using bootstrap as my style library.